# readr - how to update col_spec object from spec()

Tags: r, readr

I like the workflow regarding column specs as described in [this RStudio blog post](https://blog.rstudio.org/2016/08/05/readr-1-0-0/).  Basically, one can grab the column specification after a `read_csv` import, and then save that down for use later.  For example, from that post:

```
mtcars2 <- read_csv(readr_example("mtcars.csv"))
#> Parsed with column specification:
#> cols(
#>   mpg = col_double(),
#>   cyl = col_integer(),
#>   disp = col_double(),
#>   hp = col_integer(),
#>   drat = col_double(),
#>   wt = col_double(),
#>   qsec = col_double(),
#>   vs = col_integer(),
#>   am = col_integer(),
#>   gear = col_integer(),
#>   carb = col_integer()
#> )
# Once you've figured out the correct types
mtcars_spec <- write_rds(spec(mtcars2), "mtcars2-spec.rds")

# Every subsequent load
mtcars2 <- read_csv(
  readr_example("mtcars.csv"), 
  col_types = read_rds("mtcars2-spec.rds")
)
```

Unfortunately, the spec objects themselves are lists with attributes, but those don't match the different column specifications as provided to the `read_csv` function via the `col_types` parameter

```
> mtcars_spec$cols$cyl
<collector_integer>
> str(mtcars_spec$cols$cyl)
 list()
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_integer" "collector"
> class(mtcars_spec)
[1] "col_spec"
```

Also, the .rds files are ugly for editing in Windows (at least for me).

I'd like to be able to edit a large `col_spec` object (say, to skip certain columns, or otherwise edit the class).  I can keep guessing at the strings I'd need to edit the list, like so:

```
attr(mtcars_spec$cols$cyl,"class")[1] = "collector_skip"` # this worked!
> mtcars_spec
cols(
  mpg = col_double(),
  cyl = col_skip(),
  disp = col_double(),
  hp = col_integer(),
  drat = col_double(),
  wt = col_double(),
  qsec = col_double(),
  vs = col_integer(),
  am = col_integer(),
  gear = col_integer(),
  carb = col_integer()
)
```

But that seems awkward.  Is there a more elegant way to update the column classifications, say, as in my example, to try to skip the `mtcars$cyl` column?  Or, if not an elegant way, a way that covers all the possible types?  I don't want to do lots of guessing about how I'd implement `<collector_date>` with various date formats.

Comment: FYI, I also filed an issue regarding this issue on github here:  https://github.com/tidyverse/readr/issues/693

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a minimal version of [Jim Hester's Github post](https://github.com/tidyverse/readr/issues/693#issuecomment-350089108)

```
library(readr)
test_spec <- spec_csv('x,y,theDate,skipCol
  1,a,"21/01/2018", "skip1
  2,z,"31/01/2018", "skip2')

test_spec
#> cols(
#>   x = col_integer(),
#>   y = col_character(),
#>   theDate = col_character(),
#>   skipCol = col_character()
#> )

test_spec$cols[["theDate"]] <- col_date("%d/%m/%Y")
test_spec$cols[["skipCol"]] <- col_skip()

test_spec
#> cols(
#>   x = col_integer(),
#>   y = col_character(),
#>   theDate = col_date(format = "%d/%m/%Y"),
#>   skipCol = col_skip()
#> )
```

Notes

- You need to know the date format of your data.
- You can use readr::spec_csv() on a file